# How to configure apache proxy redirect to another server?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy-server

I have two CentOS Servers.On **server A(192.168.0.103)** I have clean apache with *CMS* and *owncloud*. My question is what should be the **Server B(apache proxy)(192.168.0.106)** configuration. I am a newbie so I am asking for detailed explanation, please.

Comment: This question over on ServerFault might have the answers you're looking for: https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another

Comment: In addition, you might need to clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve, currently your question is a legal vague on what you want the desired outcome to be.